# tkz-euclide circles present with version 3.06c have disappeared with version 4.00b

Tags: tkz-euclide

With:

- `tkz-euclide.sty`    2020/03/18 3.06c
- `tkz-base.sty`    2020/03/18 3.06c
- `tikz.sty`    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b

the following MCE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(3,0){A}
  \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
  \tkzDefPoint(1.5,-0.6){K}
  \tkzDefPoint(-1.8,1.2){L}
  \tkzDefPoint(1.2,2.25){M}
  \tkzClipCircle(O,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=K and L](O,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=L and M](O,A)
  \tkzDrawPoints[fill=red](O,A,K,L,M)
  \tkzLabelPoints[left](O,A,K,L,M)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

used to give:

[image]

With :

- `tkz-euclide.sty`     2022/01/04 4.00
- `tikz.sty`    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a

the two circles:

```
\tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=K and L](O,A)
\tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=L and M](O,A)
```

have disappeared:

[image]

and the `.log` doesn't contain any error or warning.

How to retrieve the former behavior?

Comment: I'm having an update done next week with some minor corrections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a method to make them reappear

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(3,0){A}
  \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
  \tkzDefPoint(1.5,-0.6){K}
  \tkzDefPoint(-1.8,1.2){L}
  \tkzDefPoint(1.2,2.25){M}
  \tkzClipCircle(O,A)
  \tkzDefCircle[orthogonal through=K and L](O,A) \tkzGetPoint{C1}
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=L and M](O,A) \tkzGetPoint{C2}
  \tkzDrawCircles(C1,K C2,L)
  \tkzDrawPoints[fill=red](O,A,K,L,M)
  \tkzLabelPoints[left](O,A,K,L,M)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is of course a bug. I had warned that I could not test everything alone. If you delete the clip, an error `dimension too large` appears.
So I forgot to transform a calculation from pt to cm. The wrong line is :  `\tkz@@CalcLength(tkzPointResult,#3){tkzLengthResult}` which must be  `\tkz@@CalcLengthcm(tkzPointResult,#3){tkzLengthResult}`.

I haven't seen this problem because I always prefer to use the definition macros first ...

[image]

Comment: there is another bug but it doesn't cause an error: the macro `tkzDefOrthoThroughCircle` was defined twice

Comment: When (nice!) packages are significantly improved, like yours with this 4.00 version, bugs are inevitable, so don't worry! :) Apart from that, I don't see your point when you say you ``always prefer to use the definition macros first''

Comment: @DenisBitouzé The most important principle with this package is to respect the order def, calc, draw, ... so I prefer to define the points first and then draw.  For example there was the possibility `tkzDrawLine[median]...` which I deleted because I wanted `tkzDrawLine` to only draw lines. In this case it is necessary to do `\tkzDefSpcTriangle[centroid or medial]`. I also deleted `\tkzDrawMedian`. The final idea is to introduce lua for the definition and calculation part and to use only TikZ that afterwards to trace, mark etc. So I prefer `\defCircle[ortogonal ...]` then `\DrawCircle`.